# Is there a way to make python not wait for function to finish?

Tags: python, microcontroller, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have just started with programming on a raspberry pi pico, and I was wondering if you can make python start another function, even though the other one is still running, so I want multiple functions to run at once (but with a bit of delay between them). What I have found out myself, is that there is an extension called "Threading" but I do not know how you can install that on the Pico. My current code:

The function:

```
def dimming(PinNumber):
    PinN = PWM(Pin(PinNumber))
    PinN.freq(1000)
    for duty in range(65025):
        PinN.duty_u16(duty)
        time.sleep(0.0001)
    for duty in range(65025, 0, -1):
        PinN.duty_u16(duty)
        time.sleep(0.0001)
```

The code that starts the function:

```
while True:  
    for i in range(6):
        dimming(i)
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: You probably have it installed already.  Just look at the thread-related code in this other question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74669306/raspberry-pi-pico-w-micropython-threading-and-requests-code-stops-working   But also in general I would recommend that you find another way to solve your problem without threads, because you probably don't need them and they introduce their own difficulties.

Comment: look into `asyncio` module for micropython

Answer (score 2):

i have no experience with raspberry pi, however it would be possible to run multi function with threading lib that makes specific pipe lines for each process.

```
import threading
```

sow after declaring our functions, for example :

```
def func1 ():
   pass
def func2 ():
   pass
```

now we have to create thread lines :

```
th1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
th2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)
```

in order to start processing :

```
th1.start()
th2.start()
```

end of process :

```
th1.join()
th2.join()
```

hope to be useful ...

Answer (score 0):

You can actually go ahead and use multiprocessing library which is available in python to run two functions in parallel at a same time. You can follow the below syntax

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func1():
    pass

def func2():
    pass

p1 = Process(target=func1)
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=func2)
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Comment: I currently have the problem that the raspberry Pi doesn't detect the module named 'multiprocessing', I hope I can figure out how to use it on the Pi

Comment: @luuf I don't have much experience on using python on raspberry pi's, but however I came across this article on using multiprocessing on raspberry pi's. Hope this helps you with the task https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=221505

Comment: Also can you share the error which you are getting related to 'raspberry Pi doesn't detect the module named 'multiprocessing'.

Comment: This is a pico which is an embedded board.  multiprocessing would do nothing for this product so it makes sense that it would not be available.  I write a lot of Python for the raspberry pi computer and use both multiprocessing and threading.  However, the pico is very different.  I recommended studying both asyncio and threading.  I don't have experience with asyncio but I know it is newer than the threading module.